# How do I search for equal elements that appear next to each other in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that will accept an array and find any equal elements that appear next to each other and return a count for the greatest number of occurances. For example an array with the int values of {1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6} would return a value of 3. An array with `{1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,6,7}` would return a value of four. I've tried a few different ways, but I'm struggling. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Heres the code that I have so far-

```
public class EqualElements 
{
    public static void consecutiveEqualElements(int [] elements)
    {
        int occurances = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < elements.length; index++)
        {                   
            if(elements[index] == elements[temp])
            {
                count++;
                temp++;
                index--;
            }
            else
            {       
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int [] numbers = {1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        consecutiveEqualElements(numbers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much better way to look through  an array for consecutive numbers. This will work for both unsorted and sorted arrays.

```
public static int consecutiveEqualElements(int [] elements) {
    int currentNum = elements[0];
    int currentConsecutive = 1;
    int maxConsecutive = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] == currentNum) {
            currentConsecutive++;
            maxConsecutive = Math.max(maxConsecutive, currentConsecutive);
        } else {
            currentNum = elements[i];
            currentConsecutive = 1;
        }
    }
    return maxConsecutive;
}
```

Comment: But what about consecutive numbers? This is just adding them up in total, not checking if the number was consecutive.

Comment: Maybe it is, I guess OP didn't specify. But yeah, otherwise your answer looks fine to me :)

Comment: Just changed it up for something that works for unsorted arrays just in case. Thanks for your feedback though :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a hashmap:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
```

Now iterate through the array and put every integer with its count.

```
map.put(yourIntValue, map.get(1) + 1); // if it is already stored with a value.
```

For initial condition:

```
map.put(yourIntValue,0);
```

Then again iterate and find the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You're already iterating over the array - that's good. While you do that you're interested in two numbers:

- The longest run so far. This will be your answer in the end.
- The length of the current run. You need this to update the longest run.

We create two variables for these: `maxCount` and `count`. During the loop, we increment `count` every time we encounter two consecutive elements that are equal. And to make sure `maxCount` is always up-to-date, we set it to the maximum of the longest so far, and the current length. When the next element is different from the previous, we reset `count` to 1, as this is the start of the next run.

```
public static void consecutiveEqualElements(int [] elements) {
    int count = 1;
    int maxCount = 1;

    for (int index = 1; index < elements.length; index++) {
        if (elements[index] == elements[index - 1]) {
            count++;
            maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, count);
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(maxCount);
}
```

Note: this method assumes that `elements` is not `null` or empty. You can handle these cases seperately, if they are necessary.

Comment: How is OP meant to learn anything from this? Did you want to give a brief explanation of how your code solves their problem?

Comment: count should start at 1 at the very beginning of the method as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would look like this:

```
public class EqualElements {

    public static void consecutiveEqualElements(int[] elements) {

            // Saves the maximal number of consecutive number with the
            // same numeric value
            int occurances = 0;

            // Counts how many numbers with the same value stands right
            // behind each other
            int count = 1;

            // Run from the second index because of the in the body following
            // if-clause
            for (int index = 1; index < elements.length; index++) {

                    // In case the current and the previous element
                    // have the same numeric value
                    if (elements[index] == elements[index - 1]) {
                            // Increase the count (which is initialised with 1)
                            // And save the maximal number of consecutive numbers
                            // with the same value in occurances
                            count++;
                            occurances = Math.max(occurances, count);
                    } else {
                         // If the two numbers differ, reset the counter
                         count = 1;

                    }
             }
             System.out.println(occurances);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7 };

    consecutiveEqualElements(numbers);
}
}
```

My example returns the correct solution 3. It doesn't count the last 2 since it's nonconsecutive.

Answer (score -1):

As you traverse the array, compare each element to the previous element. If the two elements are equal, increment the number of consecutive equal values you have seen. If they are not equal, check to see if you've found a new maximum, and then reset that counter to 0.

```
public static int consecutiveEqualElements(int[] elements) {
    int max = 0;
    int consecutive = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] == elements[i-1]) {
            consecutive++;
        } else {
            if (consecutive > max) {
                max = consecutive;
            }
            consecutive = 1;
        }
    }

    if (consecutive > max) {
        return consecutive;
    } else {
        return max;
    }
}
```

Notice that the method returns a value rather than printing it out. This makes the method more flexible, as you may not always want it to print to standard output.

Comment: This would print 0 for {1,1,1,1}.